# ZedGraph Custom SymbolTypes

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am using C# to create a ZedGraph which uses custom symbols for the datapoints.
I see in older posts that there was, at one point, a "**SymbolType.UserDefined**" option, but this does not seem to be present in the latest version of ZedGraph (v5.0.9.41461).
http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_SymbolType.htm

I am hoping that there is a newer/better way to do this. If so, can someone please point me towards it?

If not, can someone recommend an alternative solution?

These symbols are industry standards for the application's market, so we have to comply.

Thank you for any assistance anyone can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I found/installed version 5.1.5, and the UserDefined SymbolType  option is available in there.

All versions...
https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20dll%20only/